# Where is escaped the shortcode?

Tags: shortcode, escaping

I'm working with a function that returns a list of posts which has the same type as the actual post. Actually, it returns a list of links with title on anchor link and let to use it with a shortcode:

```
function list_this_type_posts( $atts ) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'container' => 'div',
        'ulist' => 'ul',
        'list' => 'li',
        'link' => 'a',
        'number' => '5',
    ), $atts));


    $type = get_post_type();

    $args_posts = array(
        'posts_per_page'   => 5,
        'orderby'          => 'post_date',
        'order'            => 'DESC',
        'post_type'        => $type,
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'suppress_filters' => true );

    $posts_array = get_posts( $args_posts );
    $sThisTitle = '<'.$ulist.'>';
    foreach($posts_array as $single_post) {

        $sThisTitle .= '<'.$list.'><'.$link.' class="title_list" href="'.get_permalink($single_post->ID).'" >'.(get_the_title($single_post)).'</'.$link.'></'.$list.'>';

        }
    $sThisTitle .= '</'.$ulist.'>'; 
    return $sThisTitle;
}


add_shortcode('list_posts', 'list_this_type_posts');
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

This is working right using this shortcode: `[list_posts]`, but I wonder why it doesn't work in this way:

```
$sThisTitle = '<ul>';
    foreach($posts_array as $single_post) {

        $sThisTitle .= '<li><a class="title_list" href="'.get_permalink($single_post->ID).'" >'.(get_the_title($single_post)).'</a></li>';

        }
    $sThisTitle .= '</ul>'; 
    return $sThisTitle;
```

It seems like it is escaping the html entities, but WHERE? Is it the correct way to proceed?

Comment: What HTML entities do you mean? That is, the `<` and the `>`? Or non-English characters? Or both? I tested this and the `<` and the `>` are not effected. Perhaps a plugin or your theme is applying a filter?

Comment: @s_ha_dum - When I do like the second way, I'm getting just both `get_permalink()` and `get_the_title()` outputs.